# How to kill an instance of an application

Tags: vb.net, process, instance

I am having a text file in this path "C:\Test\test.txt" when this was openeed I need to close this.

When I am trying to use the below code all the instances of notepad are closing and I don't want that to be happened and I want to close only the ".txt" file:

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
 Dim Process() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")
  For Each p As Process In Process
    p.Kill()
Next
```

Comment: are you creating the notepad instance in your program?

Comment: Yes i am creating a text file and I need to close that file.And thanks for your help I got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something as mentioned about using an if statement. Assuming you opened the file called test.

```
 Dim Process() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")      
    For Each p As Process In Process
        If p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("test") Then
            p.Kill()
        End If
    Next
```

EDIT:

To check for multiple files

simply add or to the .Contains line

```
If p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("test") Or ("blahblah") Then
p.kill()
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer and I really thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the

`Process.MainWindowTitle`

property of `p`.

Notepad's title will be `Filename.txt - Notepad`

If you started the process yourself, you can kill it using the `Process.Kill()` method.

Note that in many (most?) circumstances, killing all instances of a process isn't really a good user experience since the user may have started instances of that process on their own in addition to the instance your program launched / is attempting to close.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and can you provide me a sample code for that.

Comment: No actually I am trying to write it to the file and while writing I need to check if the file is opened and then I need to close it and write the text to it.